# Updating DB with AJAX when checkbox is checked

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database

I'm trying to update one value in my database from 0 to 1, when a checkbox is clicked. I've gone through alot of examples on this subject, but i cant seem to understand what i'm doing wrong. Im fairly new to this, and would really appreciate some help.

FORM:

```
            <form method='post'>
                <table>                             
                    <thead>                           
                    <th><div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF; width:746px;"><div class="headline1">Registrations under preparation</div></div></th>
                    </thead>
                </table>
                <table class="width_70">   
                    <thead>                           
                    <th class="headline1">Student</th>
                    <th class="headline1">Company</th>
                    <th class="headline1">Date</th>
                    <th class="headline1">P</th>
                    <th class="headline1">V</th>
                    <th class="headline1">K</th>
                    </thead>
                   <?foreach($data_array_praktikant_info as $value){if(($value[1]->studentApproved == 1) xor ($value[1]->companyApproved == 1)) {
                    ?><tr><?                         
                    ?><td><? echo $value[0]->f_name . ' ' . $value[0]->l_name;?></td>
                        <td>Dania</td>
                        <td><? echo $value[1]->approvedDate; ?></td>
                        <td><div class="approve"><input disabled  <? if($value[1]->studentApproved == 1){?>checked<?} ?> id="7" type="checkbox"><label for="7"><span></span></label></div></td>
                        <td><div class="approve"><input disabled  <? if($value[1]->companyApproved == 1){?>checked<?} ?>  id="8" type="checkbox"><label for="8"><span></span></label></div></td>
                        <td><div class="approve"><input class="approveME" value="<? $value->application_id ?>" onclick="checkCheckboxState();" <? if($value[1]->koordinatorApproved == 1){?>checked<?} }}?> id="9" type="checkbox"><label for="9"><span></span></label></div></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
```

**AJAX:**

```
function checkCheckboxState() {

    if ($('.approveME').is(':checked')) {
        var application_id = $('.approveME').first().attr( "value" );

        //tried this aswell// 

        var application_id = $('.approveME').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "approve.php",
            data: {id : application_id},
            success: function(msg) {
                alert("Data saved:" + msg);
            }
        });
    }
    ;
}
```

PHP: (approve.php)

```
 <?

 global $wpdb;

 $application_id = $_POST['application_id'];

 $date_current = Date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

 $fieldarray = array('koordinatorApproved' => 1, 'updated' => $date_current);

 $where = array('application_id' => $application_id);

 $wpdb->update('application', $fieldarray, $where);

 ?>
```

Comment: your post variable is  `id`  but in php you want to use it  as `$_POST['application_id']` , thats your problem !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_POST["application_id"]` is always going to be null since you are passing the field as `$_POST["id"]` from your AJAX.

Either change this in your PHP:

```
$application_id = $_POST["id"];
```

or this in your Javascript:

```
data: {application_id: application_id}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use below changes,

In approve.php  file,  change the
       $application_id = $_POST['application_id'];  into  $application_id = $_POST['id'];

checkCheckboxState function remove below mentioned condition so that it works as toggle like on/off else only trigger when checkbox get checked

```
if ($('.approveME').is(':checked')) {
}
```